# How to click randomly on a page using Selenium (python) and how to zoom in on a page?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I wanted to know if there was anyway for one to click randomly in within a designated area on a given page using selenium.

Additionally, does anyone know how to zoom to a specified area of a page. For instance the page is x by y,  but I want to zoom into to a coordinate area represents of a specific area in the original page, (0, 1/4 x) by (0, 1/4 y) or (1/4 x, 2/4  x)by (1/4 y, 2/4 y), the point being that the content changes when one zooms into a certain area of a page.

The code in my head looks like this:

```
For i in x:
  Page = driver.zoom((x1, x2), (y1, y2)) # where x1 to x2 is the horizontal of the page and the y1 to y2 are the vertical dimensions of where I want to look
  x_coord = random.uniform(x1, x2) #randomly pulling x coord
  y_coord = random.uniform(y1, y2) #randomly pulling y coord
  webdriver.click(x_coord, y_coord) 
  webdriver.read_page()
```

Does anyone know how this can be implemented?

Comment: get all the URLs from the area into a list. Use the `random` module to choose one of the URLs in the list. Use `Selenium` to click that URL.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use css selector when finding items that are dynamic since it is least likely to change.

```html
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hhR3DwzV2eA')


# store the current url in a variable
current_page = driver.current_url

# create an infinite loop
while True:
    try:
        # find element using css selector
        links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.content-link.spf-link.yt-uix-sessionlink.spf-link')

        # create a list and chose a random link
        l = links[randint(0, len(links) - 1)]

        # click link
        l.click()

        # check link
        new_page = driver.current_url

        # if link is the same, keep looping
        if new_page == current_page:
            continue
        else:
            # break loop if you are in a new url
            break
    except:
        continue
```

As an example I used a YT video. Say you want to click a recommended video on the right side, well, it has a unique css selector for those links.

The reason why you want to make an infinite loop is b/c when when you make a list of elements, for some reason, python doesn't do a good job expressing stored elements. Be sure you have a catch all 'except' b/c you will get Timeout Errors and such and you want to force it to click on the random link.